# One to many mapping in Entity framework with fluent api

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, mapping, relationship

I find many examples about this but no one works for me...

I have principal class:

```
public class Class1
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string desc { get; set; } 
    public virtual Class2 class2 {get; set;}
}
```

and the second class:

```
public class Class2
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string desc { get; set; } 
}
```

I am mapping `Class1` in this way

```
public class Class1Map : EntityTypeConfiguration<Class1>
{
    public Class1Map()
    {
        // Primary Key
        this.HasKey(t => t.Id);

        // Table & Column Mappings
        this.ToTable("Class1TableName");
        this.Property(t => t.id).HasColumnName("IdColumnName");
        this.Property(t => t.desc).HasColumnName("DescColumName");
    }
}
```

and this works well

but I try many ways to bind `Class2` property of `Class1` to `IdClass2ColumnName` field of `Class1Tablename` as foreign key linked to `IdColumnName` of `Class2` table without success.

As you can see I don't want to put also `IdClass2` property in `Class1`

For testing I tried without success:

```
this.HasRequired(t => t.class2)
    .WithRequiredPrincipal()
    .Map(m => m.MapKey("IdClass2ColumnName "));


this.HasRequired(t => t.class2)
    .WithMany()
    .Map(m => m.MapKey("IdClass2ColumnName"));
```

Comment: After some works the db was created (even if AutomaticMigrationsEnabled property set in Configuration does not work...) but in Class1TableName found no IdClass2ColumnName field but class2_id one

Comment: Additional info: every class2 entry in table can be used in many class1 entry, it's a simply type table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, was a problem in code migration, I forget to update code migration class and so EF use old column name.

The correct mapping syntax is

```
this.HasRequired(t => t.class2)
    .WithRequiredDependent()
    .Map(m => m.MapKey("IdClass2ColumnName "));
```